# permission problem - user cannot save changes even though user has full access

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, navigation, site-settings, sharepoint-permissions

I have the problem that I am a website owner and have full access, but I cannot make any changes under the point website settings\navigation.

If I click OK, I get the message that I don't have access to it. I have already given myself full access several times.

The funny thing is that I can make an access request with the message "No access" and I get it myself.

I confirmed this to myself, but it doesn't work either. I am desperate and hope that you can help me.

Comment: Have you activated the Publishing feature on your site?

Comment: Yes, I have activated the Publishing feature on my site.

Comment: I have also faced the similar problem in SharePoint Online when Publishing feature is activated...It show access denied error but saves all the changes made in Navigation settings? Do you need Publishing feature in your site for any particular reason?

Comment: Also, If you need this feature then try activating it on both site collection & site level and check if it still throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot your issue as following:

1. Whether the website is top-level site or a subsite? Make sure you have permission on the top-level site and check again.
2. In the site settings->Site permissions->check permissions, check if the "Add and Customize page" permission is set to Deny.

   If so, you can use PowerShell command to allow "Add and Customize page": [Allow or prevent custom script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fAllow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f), wait up to 24 hours to bring this setting into effect in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

I have also observed the similar behavior in SharePoint Online site **when Publishing feature is activated**.

It show access denied error but saves all the changes made in Navigation settings.

If you are not using the Publishing feature for any other requirement/reason in your site then you can try deactivating this feature.